# Perform same action on all selected objects

Tags: python, add-on, selection-tools

I am trying to write a simple code that should perform the same action on all selected objects in Blender. For example, let's assume that I have two MESH objects in my scene and I want to print the scale along the x-axis of these two "MESH" objects. Here the code:

```
import bpy
objects = bpy.context.scene.objects
for obj in objects:
   obj.select_set(obj.type == "MESH")
selected_objects = bpy.context.selected_objects
for cube in selected_objects:
   print(bpy.context.object.scale[0])
```

The problem is that the code prints twice the same value, which refers to the last selected object (the one with the light yellow border). I can't understand why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you noticed, `bpy.context.object` points to the active object, regardless of the variable in your `for` loop.

In your last line you are iterating over all selected objects, but you are not actually using the iteration variable afterwards, `cube`.

Replace the last line with `print(cube.scale[0])`